# PHP - Grab the code that threw an error

Tags: php, error-handling

I'd like to be able to grab the actual line of code (not the number, the line of code text) where a NOTICE error occurred.  Is there any way to accomplish this?  I can't seem to find a function that will return the code on a certain line # in the currently running script.

Comment: [Set the error handler to throw an `ErrorException`](http://php.net/manual/class.errorexception.php#errorexception.example.error-handler) then pull the first line from the [stack trace](http://php.net/manual/exception.gettrace.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the PHP script has permissions to read the current file, you can do this:

```
<?php

echo $b; // Undefined variable

$errors = error_get_last();

$errorMessage = $errors['message'];    
$pathToScript = $errors['file'];
$line = $errors['line'];

$arrayOfLines = file(__FILE__);

echo "The error message was: '$errorMessage occured in $pathToScript'";
echo "The line of code that caused the error is: \n";

highlight_string($arrayOfLines[$line-1]);
```

Output:

> The error message was: 'Undefined variable: b occured in /path/to/script.php'
>
> The line of code that caused the error is: `echo $b;`